# htaccess to remove .php and rename folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm using php for a native project
my urls are as follows project.log/share/report1.php

i want to remove .php from urls, if the url entered contained .php remove it, if not act as if it's found

share folder i want to show it as reports too and works vice versa

what i've achieved so far

```
 RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]
```

this successfully remove the .php but i don't know how to add an expression for share folder to replace it's name

Comment: What do you mean by **share folder** ? Do you a folder and and file of identical names?

Answer (score 1):

You need additional rule to rename `share` to `reports`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^share/(.*?)(\.php)?$ /reports/$1 [R=307,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=307,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/share/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^reports/(.*)$ share/$1.php [END,NC]

RewriteRule ^reports/(.*)$ share/$1 [END,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [NC,END]
```

Comment: working pretty good but when a page contains post request, like login page , the page refreshes not executing the requests

Comment: (post is sent but reply from debugger network is empty)